# prefer to V rather than V/Ving

Tags: infinitive-vs-gerund

I'd like o know which form of verb should follow "rather than" in the following:

> John prefers to watch TV rather than play/playing basketball.

Comment: Both verbs should be in the same form - _prefers to watch rather than play_ or _prefers watching to playing_.

Answer (score 1):

The two verbs should be in the same form.

> - John prefers to watch TV rather than play basketball. [image: Correct, shown by green check mark]
> - John prefers watching TV to playing basketball. [image: Correct, shown by green check mark]
> - John prefers to watch TV rather than playing  basketball. [image]
> - John prefers watching TV to  play basketball.  [image]

The 4th could be correct with a very different meaning if watching TV was a means of playing basketball, perhaps in a video game form. But it can't be used to mean anything like the first two. In practice, this is most likely to be a simple error.

I also think that "rather than" doesn't sound natural with the "-ing" forms, so I have modified that example.